# How is IXRTextBlockPtr used?

Tags: c++, silverlight

How is IXRTextBlockPtr used?

I have a XAML file that is made by Expression Blend.  But the Silverlight project that corresponds to it has to be in C++ instead of C#  (it has something to do with being part of an embedded system).

The automatically gernerated C++ code referrs to the TextBlock code in the header file like this:

```
IXRTextBlockPtr            m_pFoo;            // <TextBlock x:Name="Foo">
```

So how do I assign a value to the text block such that it appears in the window defined in the XAML?

There does not seem to be much information to be googled about IXRTextBlockPtr.

Comment: It is an auto-generated type, derived from _com_ptr_t, that you got from importing the type library.  You are heading for a concrete wall about half a mile thick, you cannot run C++ code in the Silverlight host.  Only verifiable managed code is allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [formal MSDN documentation for `IXRTextBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee502508.aspx) tells you exactly what to do: look at the [`XRPtr<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee502937.aspx) smart-pointer for `IXRTextBlockPtr`'s interface.

If we then look at the `XRPtr<>` class template, we see it has [`operator=`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee503985.aspx) and [`Attach()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee502749.aspx). Presumably `operator=` will suit your needs.

Comment: the method is "SetText" and takes a Wide Character pointer (WCHAR*).  How do you convert a character array to a Wide Character pointer?

Comment: @xarzu : There are many ways; the standard-supported way is `std::mbstowcs`. If you're using MFC or ATL, then the `CA2CW` macro is handier. Of course, the **best** solution is to work solely with wide characters to begin with so you won't have this problem.